# How can I emit socket event in useEffect based on route params?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I use `React` and `Socket.io` to create some kind of Slack clone. In my case I'm trying to integrate `namespaces` and `rooms` together.

I join to the `namespace` by passing route params in my `React Router` route.

I have following routes:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path={'/server/:id'} component={ServerContentPage} />
</Switch>
```

and inside the ServerContentPage I have:

```
<Route exact path={'/server/:id/room/:roomID'} component={ChatPage} />
```

so ChatPage route is nested inside the ServerContentPage.

Joining namespace (rendering ServerContentPage) works properly, then I map all rooms fetched from the `MongoDB` database and create a React Links, which redirects me to the correct route and renders component correctly.

```
{rooms.map(room => (
  <StyledLink to={`/server/${currentNamespaceID}/room/${room._id}`} key={room._id}>
    <StyledParagraph>{room.name}</StyledParagraph>
  </StyledLink>
))}
```

When I click on the `Link` it renders `ChatPage` as expected, then I want this page to emit socket to the server with the roomID, which will be my room I have to join.

- ChatPage.js

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import NamespaceSocketContext from '../providers/namespaceSocketContext';


const ChatPage = ({ match, setCurrentRoom }) => {
  const { namespaceSocket } = useContext(NamespaceSocketContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    namespaceSocket.emit('join_room', match.params.roomID);
    console.log('should emit join');


    namespaceSocket.on('user_joined', roomID => {
      console.log(`user joined to the room room ${roomID}`);
      setCurrentRoom(roomID);
    });

    namespaceSocket.on('user_left', roomID => {
      console.log(`user left room ${roomID}`);
      setCurrentRoom(null);
    });

    return () => {
      console.log('should emit leave');
      namespaceSocket.emit('leave_room', match.params.roomID);
    };
  }, [match.params.roomID]);


  return (
    <p>...some content</p>
  );
};


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    setCurrentRoom: roomID => dispatch(setCurrentRoom(roomID))
  };
};


export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ChatPage);
```

Because of the nested routes, I use context to provide socket that is connected to the current namespace.

- index.js (server)

```
namespaceController
    .getAllNamespaces()
    .then(namespaces =>
      namespaces.map(item => {
        io.of(`/${item._id}`)
          .use((namespaceSocket, next) => {
            socketAuthentication(namespaceSocket, next);
          })
          .on('connection', namespaceSocket => {
            const currentNamespace = io.of(`/${item._id}`);

            /* join room */
            namespaceSocket.on('join_room', roomID => {

              namespaceSocket.join(roomID);
              console.log(`user joined room ${roomID}`);

              /* emit event back, user joined to the room */
              namespaceSocket.emit('user_joined', roomID);
            });

            /* leave room */
            namespaceSocket.on('leave_room', roomID => {
              namespaceSocket.leave(roomID);

              namespaceSocket.emit('user_left', roomID);
              console.log(`User left room ${roomID}`);
            });
          });
      })
    )
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

When I will open this ChatPage through the React Router Link I got this output on my browser console:

```
should emit join
```

which may look correct, but server is not joining the room. On my server console I will never get `user joined room {some.id}`. Additionally when I will want to change the room by clicking another link, I will get this output on my browser console:

```
should emit leave
should emit join
user left room {some.id}
```

So again it looks like cleanup function works properly, it cause the server to leave the room, it sends `user_left` event back to the client, but it will not join the room, even instead of this console log.

- I tried to use a little bit different approach and add to the Link `onClick` function which could emit `join_room` event when link is clicked, then remove `namespaceSocket.emit('join_room', match.params.roomID)` from the `ChatPage` useEffect.

**It works, but** it is kind of weird, because `join_room` event is emitted to the server on the first Link click, client joined to the room, but I don't have any server response on the client side. Only after the second click I've got `user joined room {some.id}` back.

It might be the useEffect match.params problem, but I can't find the solution. Maybe someone will be able to help me.